# Array index out of range?

Tags: c#, arrays, unity-game-engine

I have prefabs created, named with `0, 1 ... 9`.

I want to create a numbers with `rigidbody` and `collision`. However I am receiving the exception below:

> IndexOutOfRangeException: Array index is out of range.
>   (wrapper stelemref) object:stelemref (object,intptr,object)
>   Spawn_Score.Start () (at Assets/Spawn_Score.cs:17)

Code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Spawn_Score : MonoBehaviour {

  private Vector3 startPosition;
  private Quaternion startRotation;

  public GameObject[] number_object;

  public int position;
  public int count;

  // Use this for initialization
  void Start () {
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        number_object [i] = (GameObject)Resources.Load (i.ToString());
    }
    GenerateScore ();
  }

  // Update is called once per frame
  void Update () {

  }

  void GenerateScore() {
    startRotation = transform.rotation;
    count = PlayerPrefs.GetInt ("PlayerScore").ToString ().Length;
    for (int i = 1; i < count; i++) {
        //int number;
        startPosition = new Vector3 (2f*i, 5.6f, 0);
        //number = (int)PlayerPrefs.GetInt("PlayerScore").ToString()[i];
        Instantiate (number_object[1], startPosition, startRotation);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You haven't shown us where `number_object` is initialized. (You've shown us where the array is populated, but not where you're actually initializing the variable.)

Comment: It's everything I have. Isn't the number_object initialized at top of the page? If I'm correct.

Comment: No, it's *declared* early in the code, but it would have the default value of `null`. So something must be initializing it, otherwise you'd get a `NullReferenceException`. It's possible that some magic part of Unity is initializing it automatically, but I don't see how it would know how large to make the array.

Comment: Well the 10 is amount of prefabs I have named '0' -> '9' so I don't understand can't I simply put them in manually, because amount of these isn't going to change. For loop should do that at Starting void.

Comment: I think you're missing the point. How do you expect that loop to work unless the variable has been initialized with a large enough array?

Comment: I guess the array is initialized by the inspector with a size of 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should put dummy placeholders for public GameObject[] number_object; in your editor. You can't dynamically generate without knowing the size. You're dynamically trying to populate and size[] before initializing. It's not a stack as you can't push and pop things extemporaneously. I'd put a dummy prefab object (9 to be exact), the same one is fine. That way you'll allocate 9 objects, and the size will be consistent, and you can populate change number_object[i] anytime you want!

Create a dummy_prefab, and size the GameObject array in Unity to 9, and then select dummy_prefab as the same value for each. They will be placeholders, it doesn't matter if it's the same or different random GameObject types!

In UnityScript I've done something similar in my game. Note that this isn't in C# but JS.  But for LevelPieces and LevelPiecesXPosition I had to size it in the editor ahead of time. I had the same array error before I had done it this way:

```
public var LevelPieces: GameObject[];
public var LevelPiecesXPosition: float[];

function Start {

  for (var x:int=0;x < LevelPieces.Length;x++) {
      var temp:GameObject = Instantiate(LevelPieces[x], Vector3(LevelPiecesXPosition[x],0,0), Quaternion.Euler(0,0,0));
  }

}
```